# SSIS Flat File Import errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have a ssis job that imports flat file data into my database and also data conversion. Please find a view of the scheme:

[image: SSIS schema]

The issue is that I keep getting errors on the "Violations" field see below:

> [Flat File Source [37]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data
> conversion for column "Violations" returned status value 4 and status
> text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the
> target code page.".
>
> [Flat File Source [37]] Error: The "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File
> Source Output].Columns[Violations]" failed because truncation
> occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Flat File
> Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Violations]" specifies
> failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified
> object of the specified component.
> [Flat File Source [37]] Error: An error occurred while processing file
> "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\Food_Inspections.csv"
> on data row 25.

In line 25 of the CSV file, this field is over 4000 characters long.
In data conversion, I currently have the Data Type set to string [DT_STR] of length 8000, coding 65001.
Row delimiter `{LF}`,
Column delimiter Semicolon `{;}`
I have already looked at other suggested solutions, i.e. increasing OutputColumnWidth to 5000 but it did not help - please advise how to solve this.

Comment: Have you considered using `dt_text` or the Unicode equivalent if you need characters outside the of the code page you're using characters too?

Comment: @Larnu yes I want to use Unicode but continues to get an error after the transformation

Comment: `dt_str` can't use characters outside of the code page you define; as the error is **literally** telling Use `dt_wstr`/`dt_next` and `nvarchar`

Comment: @Larnu see: I have DT_STR in the file input, but I want to convert it to DT_WSTR in the Output (this is the data type I have in the DB). When I try to do it, I get the error described in the description

Comment: When you convert the data to a `DT_STR` it's already too late; you've lost the data and the error occurs.

Comment: @Larnu Then what should I set for the 'Violations' field on Input in File Conncection Manager ?

Comment: As I said: *"Use `dt_wstr`/`dt_ntext` and `nvarchar`"*

Comment: @Larnu But after changing Violations field on Input to dt_wstr I have still the same error code - I suspect that on Output I have set the character limit to 4000 (I can't set more for dt_wstr)

Comment: ... you're not reading what I'm typing,.. `dt_wstr`/ ***`dt_ntext`***... the values over 4,000 characters you need `dt_ntext`. And nmke sure it's the right data type and size for the entire data flow. The errors are **literally** telling you the problem, and where. Read them, and address the. Basic debugging.